# How to add authentication token in header in Picasso library

Tags: android, picasso, okhttp

I am using the `picasso` library to download the bitmap so in the api I need to pass the token in the headers. I tried below code from this thread [Android Picasso library, How to add authentication headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273783/android-picasso-library-how-to-add-authentication-headers)

```
public static Picasso getImageLoader(final Context context) {
    // fetch the auth value
    sSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext());

    Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(context);
    builder.downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(context) {
        @Override
        protected HttpURLConnection openConnection(Uri uri) throws IOException {
            HttpURLConnection connection = super.openConnection(uri);
            connection.setRequestProperty(Constant.HEADER_X_API_KEY, sSharedPreferences.getString(SharedPreferenceKeys.JSESSIONID, ""));
            return connection;
        }
    });
    sPicasso = builder.build();
    return sPicasso;
}
```

### Picasso Request

```
mTarget = new Target() {
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom loadedFrom) {
        mdpImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        Logger.d(TAG, "Test");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable drawable) {
        Logger.d(TAG, "Test");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable drawable) {
        Logger.d(TAG, "Test");
    }
};

CustomPicasso.getImageLoader(getActivity()).with(getActivity()).load(URL).into(mTarget);
```

### Question

I debugged my code & I see it never called `openconnection` override method of `OkHttpDownloader` so my request always fail & at the end it calls `onBitmapFailed`.

Please help what are things I have to do to pass headers value correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It took two days to resolve this problem. For custom downloader you don't have to call `with` method because this will initialize the default downloader & picasso instance. Simply do below like this that will help you to get bitmap.

```
Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(getActivity());
picasso =  builder.downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(getActivity()) {
    @Override
    protected HttpURLConnection openConnection(Uri uri) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection connection = super.openConnection(uri);
        connection.setRequestProperty(Constant.HEADER_X_API_KEY, mSharedPreferences.getString(SharedPreferenceKeys.JSESSIONID, ""));
        return connection;
    }
}).build();
picasso.load(url).into(mTarget);
```

Answer (score 1):

This finally worked for me, just call it and then use the picasso instance, here I add an access token. But you could also add username and password.

```
private void setupPicasso()
{        
    //need to set picasso up to use auth - took a while to work this out!
    final Context c = context;
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    String token = <token you got when you logged in>;
                    String authString = "Bearer "+token;                        
                    Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                            .addHeader("Authorization", authString)
                            .build();
                    return chain.proceed(newRequest);
                }
            })
            .build();
    picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context)
            .downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(client))
            .build();
}
```

Comment: The cache doesn't work with custom OkHttpClient using Picasso. Bad For recyclerview. But GLide does. But the Recyclerview Scroll is not smooth in the case of Glide.

Answer (score 0):

```
Picasso picasso;
Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(this);
picasso = builder.loader(new BasicAuthOkHttpLoader(this)).build();
```

implement Loader to BasicAuthOkHttpLoader class.

In override Load method, write ur authentication logic.

```
 @Override
  public Response load(String url, boolean localCacheOnly) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection connection = client.open(new URL(url));
    String authString = "username:password";
    String authStringEnc = Base64.encodeToString(authString.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
    connection.setUseCaches(true);

    // no caching happens without this setting in our scenario
    connection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "max-stale=2592000");// 30 days
    if (localCacheOnly) {
      connection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "only-if-cached");
    }

    boolean fromCache = parseResponseSourceHeader(connection.getHeaderField(RESPONSE_SOURCE));

    return new Response(connection.getInputStream(), fromCache);
  }
```

For more details: [http Basic auth the implementation of a custom loader](https://gist.github.com/dkunzler/5636491)

Comment: Some of classes in that code has been deprecated. Please specify the version of picasso & okhttp library i should use for these.

Comment: picasso-1.1.1.jar is available

Answer (score 0):

I used another library AQuery and was able to get not only authorized access to picassa rolling in a few minutes but also the library used the phones credentials so it was extremely easy.

***Even if you don't use this library take a look at how I get the experimental method of including only the fields needed working below.  The smaller results makes for faster network io and a huge difference in CPU.  Because the JSON is smaller it parses faster and or the DOM for the xml is smaller it is built extremely fast.***

Here I'm using the experimental method of returning only fields I want for public albums for the user in XML.

```
GoogleHandle handle = new GoogleHandle(this.getActivity(),
            AQuery.AUTH_PICASA, AQuery.ACTIVE_ACCOUNT);

    // experimental fields method encoding the data part of the query string only.
    String url = "";
    try {
        url = "https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/default?kind=album&access=public&fields="
                + URLEncoder
                        .encode("entry(title,id,gphoto:numphotosremaining,gphoto:numphotos,media:group/media:thumbnail)",
                                "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        //whatever I know this will work
        // I hard coded the string.
    }


        aq.auth(handle).progress(R.id.pbTrackerAlbumsProgress)
                .ajax(url, XmlDom.class, this, "renderAlbums");



public void renderAlbums(String url, XmlDom xml, AjaxStatus status) {
    List<PicasaAlbum> entries = convertAll(xml);


    if (entries.size() > 0) {
        isAuthError = false;
        // if the xml iis null we can't display the list
        // we can setup the adapter
        aa = new ArrayAdapter<PicasaAlbum>(this.getActivity(),
                R.layout.listview_item_album, entries) {

            public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {

                if (convertView == null) {

                    // convertView =
                    // View.inflate(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                    // R.layout.listview_item_album, parent);
                    convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                            .inflate(R.layout.listview_item_album, parent,
                                    false);
                }

                PicasaAlbum picasaAlbum = getItem(position);

                AQuery aqLocal = aq.recycle(convertView);

                aqLocal.id(R.id.albumTitle).text(picasaAlbum.title);
                // aq.id(R.id.meta).text(picasaAlbum.author);

                String tbUrl = picasaAlbum.thumbNailUrl.toString();

                Bitmap placeholder = aqLocal
                        .getCachedImage(R.drawable.ic_launcher2);

                if (aqLocal.shouldDelay(position, convertView, parent,
                        tbUrl)) {

                    aqLocal.id(R.id.tb).image(placeholder);
                } else {
                    aqLocal.id(R.id.tb).image(tbUrl, true, true, 0,
                            R.drawable.ic_launcher2x, placeholder,
                            AQuery.FADE_IN_NETWORK, 0);
                }

                return convertView;

            }

        };
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTrackerExistingAlbum))
                .setText("Select the album for route marker photos");
        ((ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.pbTrackerAlbumsProgress))
                .setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvTrackerAlbums);

        lv.setAdapter(aa);
        aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
        lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Picasso 2.5, The okHttpDownloader has changed. Please refer the below link to add the authentication headers

https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/900