# Picasso not loading pictures in ImageView

Tags: android, ssl, picasso, okhttp

I'm trying to use Picasso in order to make a lazy picture loading in a ListView. But it's actually not working. In my custom adapter, I get the ImageView, initialize a Picasso object and indicate to load the image into the specified ImageView.
To retrieve picture from server, I needed to provide a basic authentication, so I've created a custom interceptor which adds the authentication header.
Moreover, I need to trust every SSL certificate because for the moment the certificate is not signed. 
The behaviors that I faced:

1. Authentication error --> I've added the header. The error disappears.
2. SSL certificate trust error --> I've added an SslSocketFactory, the same one that I use for all my volley requests. The error disappears.

But still any pictures are loading and now any errors appears.

Above, the code that builds the Picasso Object:

```
public Picasso getPicassoDownloader() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException
{


    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { 
            new X509TrustManager() {

                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}


                @Override
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    X509Certificate[] myTrustedAnchors = new X509Certificate[0];  
                    return myTrustedAnchors;
                }
            }
        };

     SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
     sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());


    Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(getContext()).listener(new Listener() {

        @Override
        public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso arg0, Uri arg1, Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
    });

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    client.setSslSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    client.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {

        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }
    });

    client.networkInterceptors().add(new BasicAuthInterceptor());

    Downloader downloader = new OkHttpDownloader(client);

    return builder.downloader(downloader).build();
}
```

Then, How I use the Picasso object into the getView method of my adapter:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.productImage);

            Picasso picasso = null;

            picasso.load(produit.getImageDefaultUri()).fit().into(imageView, new Callback(){

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    System.out.println("Error");

                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    System.out.println("Success");

                }

            });
```

Here is the inflated layout which contains the ImageView where the picture has to be loaded.

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/productImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:contentDescription="Product Image" />

            <ProgressBar
              android:id="@+id/progressBar"
              style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
              android:layout_centerVertical="true"
              android:visibility="visible"
              android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progressbar" >
           </ProgressBar>

         </RelativeLayout>
```

Would be great if somebody could help me with that ! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This seems too obvious of a mistake, but you use a null Picasso reference instead of using `Picasso picasso = getPicassoDownloader();`. I was having a similar issue and solved it using your example and [How to add authentication token in header in Picasso library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26126223/how-to-add-authentication-token-in-header-in-picasso-library).

Comment: Thank you but it's a mistake, I retrieve a picasso object, just forget to add it in the question.

Comment: Nop did not manage to make it work. I take up another solution: **NetworkImageView** provided by the Volley library.