# Download base64 encode image using picasso lib in android

Tags: android, picasso

I want to load base64 encode image using picsso lib.

```
mImage=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageload_image);
Picasso.with(this).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(mImage);
```

above code work fine but when i change url

https://bma8.officebrain.com/web/binary/image?model=mail.group&field=image_small&id=1

Can not load image in imageview.

Is there another way to load image?

Please help me.

Comment: your url is not working.

Comment: Paste in firefox browser it's working

Comment: what it is limited to firfox only ?

Comment: I don't know. I thing firefox automatic handle base 64 encoded image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to intercept the answer and change it, try this solution [click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42852617/3395978)

Answer (score -3):

Try

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(strBase64, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length); 
image.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
```