# How to add header to Android Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

I'm trying to add an authentication header to Picasso.  I have followed the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273783/android-picasso-library-how-to-add-authentication-headers), but when I get to the last line

```
new Picasso.Builder(mContext).downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(picassoClient)).build();
```

I get an error `Cannot resolve constructor 'OkHttpDownloader(okhttp3.OkHttpClient)'`

I looked for a matching namespace to what the constructor expects but couldn't find one.  Am I using the wrong versions of one of these or is it something else? Here are my import statements and versions:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.1.2'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add `Interceptor` to the `OkHttpClient` you are providing to the constructor of `OkHttpDownloader`.

Also you need to use this [OkHttp3Downloader](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/c2b317bf51bcea7ef0f72cf0bf42d94b92cd45d6/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/OkHttp3Downloader.java) instead, which is support for okhttp3. Probably, you might want to use a [snapshot version](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/squareup/picasso/picasso/) of the picasso where `OkHttp3Downloader` is probably included in the library.

Reader more about `Interceptor`s [here](https://publicobject.com/2014/12/31/okhttp-2-2-has-interceptors/)

Comment: Thank you.  Instead of changing my version of Picasso, I imported a version of OkHttp3Downloader using `compile 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.0.2'`