# Android Picasso, add custom HTTP header in version 2.5.2

Tags: android, picasso

I've tried several solutions on SO but none worked for me.

How to add a custom **HTTP header** in android **Picasso** library version 2.5.2?

Comment: please give more information about you question

Comment: Well, the question is short but completely clear I think, I don't really know what details to add more ;)

Comment: where use to header and many meanings of header as like listview header any image header, you have to specify of you try.

Comment: So, your general approach was to create an `OkHttpClient` with an `Interceptor` that adds the header, then wrap the client in an `OkHttpDownloader` and use that to construct the `Picasso` instance that you set with `Picasso.setSingletonInstance()` *before* you ever call `Picasso.with()`? Right?

Comment: I might be mistaken but Picasso as in the image loader from Square? Why in the world do you want to manipulate HTTP headers from an image loader?

Comment: @david.mihola, exactly: Picasso singleton, and I not calling Picasso.with()

Comment: @ridsatrio because Picasso can load images from url, and this endpoint requires authentication in my case

Comment: @Manza: How do you not use `Picasso.with()`? I think this would really be easier if you pasted some of you code...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on [Android Picasso library, How to add authentication headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273783/android-picasso-library-how-to-add-authentication-headers)

I've solved in this way

dependencies:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
```

Code

```
 OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
 okHttpClient.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
 @Override
 public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
 Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
               .addHeader("X-CUSTOM-HEADER", "my-header-value")
               .build();
                return chain.proceed(newRequest);
            }
        });

 return new Picasso.Builder(context).downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(okHttpClient)).build();
```

Thanks for help