# Android Picasso add header on load

Tags: android, picasso

I am trying to add header authorization while loading by url img. I tested in postman it works fine , but on mobile device it doesnt work.

Here is the code:

```
private Picasso getPicasso() {
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    okHttpClient.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + userPrefs.accessToken().get())
                    .build();
            return chain.proceed(newRequest);
        }
    });

    return new Picasso.Builder(getActivity()).downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(okHttpClient)).build();
}
```

And how i use it :

```
getPicasso().load(ServiceGateway.API_BASE_URL + "me/avatar")
        .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
        .into(ivUserImage);
```

Gradle:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
```

What i am doing wrong here ?

Comment: did you checked this link.. ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273783/android-picasso-library-how-to-add-authentication-headers

Comment: yes didnt work for me

Comment: Same for me, `newRequest` was not called at all.