# Load Images by passing authentication token Picasso Xamarin

Tags: android, authentication, xamarin, access-token, picasso

I am using the Picasso component to load my images from the url into an `ImageView`. The issue is that I need to pass an Authentication token in the headers along with the URL to make sure I have access to it.

How can I pass the Authentication token along with the URL using the Picasso component?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Picasso library, How to add authentication headers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273783/android-picasso-library-how-to-add-authentication-headers)

Comment: ...and about url: `url += ("?or&token=" + token)`

Comment: @indramurari I have gone through that one already. I wanted something equivalent in xamarin

Comment: @Selvin thanks for the help but it didnt work. Still gives me and unauthorized error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Picasso library on NuGet and the Xamarin Component store is super old. It hasn't been updated in over a year. Hence there might be slight differences from the code you see out there from what you have available.

If you need to add a header to your image requests you can implement your own `IDownloader` which you hand to Picasso:

```
public class CustomDownloader : OkHttpDownloader
{
    public CustomDownloader(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transfer) 
        : base(handle, transfer)
    { }

    public CustomDownloader(string authtoken, Context context) : base(context)
    {
        Client.Interceptors().Add(new MyInterceptor(authtoken));
    }

    public class MyInterceptor : Java.Lang.Object, IInterceptor
    {
        private string _authtoken;

        public MyInterceptor(string authtoken)
        {
            _authtoken = authtoken;
        }

        public Response Intercept(IInterceptorChain chain)
        {
            var newRequest = chain.Request().NewBuilder().AddHeader("Authentication", _authtoken).Build();
            return chain.Proceed(newRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

You can then add this custom downloader like:

```
var token = "authtoken";
var builder = new Picasso.Builder(this).Downloader(new CustomDownloader(token, this)).Build();
```

Then as usual you can download your image into an `ImageView` as usual with:

```
builder.Load(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("https://test.com/img.jpg")).Into(imageView);
```

I've tested this against Requestb.in and the `Authentication` header is set just fine.

You can obviously set any header you want.

Comment: the component is a bit old, but the NuGet is up to date. I have just finished the binding of Jake's library and it will be up on NuGet soon.

Comment: By default, Picasso uses OkHttp v2, and Jake's downloader uses v3.

Answer (score 5):

Just finished binding the library by Jake:
 - Java: https://github.com/JakeWharton/picasso2-okhttp3-downloader
 - C#: https://github.com/mattleibow/square-bindings

The NuGet is [`JakeWharton.Picasso2OkHttp3Downloader`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JakeWharton.Picasso2OkHttp3Downloader/) (there may be a delay for the package to propagte around the world):

```
> Install-Package JakeWharton.Picasso2OkHttp3Downloader
```

This can be used in the same way from C#:

```cs
using Square.OkHttp3;
using Square.Picasso;
using JakeWharton.Picasso;

// create the client
var client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .AddInterceptor(chain =>
    {
        var newRequest = chain.Request()
            .NewBuilder()
            .AddHeader("X-TOKEN", "VAL")
            .Build();
        return chain.Proceed(newRequest);
    })
    .Build();

// create the picasso handle
var picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context)
    .Downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(client))
    .Build();

// use picasso!
picasso
    .Load(url)
    .Placeholder(Resource.Drawable.placeholder)
    .Error(Resource.Drawable.error)
    .CenterInside()
    .Into(holder.image);
```

Note: this library use OkHttp v3. If this is not desired for some reason (should not cause any issues), then you will have to make use of [answer provided by Cheesebaron](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39839257/1117914).