# How to add authentication headers in Xamarin Picasso library

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, picasso

I'm attempting to add authentication headers while loading images using the Xamarin version of the Picasso library. I see other threads for how to do it using native Android (e.g. [Android Picasso library, How to add authentication headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273783/android-picasso-library-how-to-add-authentication-headers)), however I'm not seeing the same properties and methods available in Xamarin. Has anyone accomplished this?

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("X-TOKEN", "VAL")
                        .build();
                return chain.proceed(newRequest);
            }
        })
        .build();

Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context)
        .downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(client))
        .build();
```

Comment: I don't think that there's an "official" Xamarin version of Picasso, so check if the version that you are using is updated. Given that you are using Xamarin, I advise you replace Picasso with FFImageLoading https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading

Comment: I actually just recently switched from FFImageLoading to Picasso, I kept running into bugs with FFImageLoading and there is only one developer maintaining it so you are at the mercy of their availability.

Comment: Perhaps this NuGet? https://www.nuget.org/packages/JakeWharton.Picasso2OkHttp3Downloader/